# postgres: import csv file into table

Tags: postgresql

I want to import the csv file into database table .but it was not working..

I run the bash shell in the linux env .

```
CREATE TABLE test.targetDB (
    no int4 NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    year varchar(15) NOT NULL,
    name bpchar(12) NOT NULL,
    city varchar(15) NOT NULL,
    ts_load timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (seq_no)
)
```

`test.csv` file

```
"2019","112         ","1123",2019-07-26-05.33.43.000000
```

Linux `Cmd`

```
psql -d $database -c   " COPY test.targetDB from 'test.csv' delimiter ',' csv "
```

Error

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "2019"
CONTEXT:  COPY targetDB, line 1, column no: "2019"
```

How can I resolve this issue

Comment: It seemed  "2019" is copy into the  column no ? but the column no is automatic GENERATED in the database table when i insert data.

Comment: Unrelated, but: why use `varchar` for a colum named **year**? Shouldn't that be an `integer`? Also: do **not** use `char` or `bpchar`. Those type have absolutely not advantages, but have many disadvantages.

Comment: Great idea . Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell copy, that the `no` column is not part of the CSV file by specifying the columns that should be populated:

```
COPY test.targetDB(year, name, city, ts_load) from 'test.csv' delimiter ',' csv
```

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend, using datagrip - a postgresql client tool. You can use a evaluation version if you don't wish to purchase. It's pretty simple from the UI to import a file rather using a command line.

Comment: Thank you for your commend . But i have to use the shell to import the data into database.